# Adicionar novo csproj em projeto xamarin.forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Necessito criar um outro csproj em minha solution Xamarin.Forms. Devo criar um outro PCL? Acho que sim. Criar um do Windows creio não funcionar, certo? Fiz isso e veio buttons e etc. Como assim? Mas devo adicionar um novo projeto do tipo PCL ou não:

Comment: Creio que uma biblioteca de classes do windows é suficiente, poiis o objetivo é apenas gerar uma DLL